# Fast where() function in C++

Tags: c++, where-clause

I have an integer array filled with 0s and 1s. I am looking for the fastest way in C/C++ to get the positions (indices) of the 1s, something similar to the where() function in numpy.

Edit 1: since I only store bits, a char array would do the job just as fine.

Edit 2: an example:

```
char a[5];
a[0]=0;
a[1]=1;
a[2]=1;
a[3]=0;
a[4]=1;
```

should return

```
1,2,4
```

The type of the array is not crucial, however I have to find the position of 1s as fast as possible.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post some code (what kind of array, what content....)

Comment: Python does not have `where` function. It is part of `numpy` which is not part of python standard library.

Comment: Search the web for "bit twiddling bit count".

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store only bits, I suppose you could just use bool type, not char.

```
const unsigned int size = 5;

bool bits[size] = {0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0};
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;

auto ptr = &bits[0];
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++, ptr++)
{
    if (*ptr) indices.push_back (i);    
}
```

If speed is more important than memory for you, you could use regular (statically-sized) array, instead of std::vector (it takes time to "enlarge" it), an cope with over-allocation.

I recommend you to somehow judge approximate size of your bit array and use reserve() function of your indices vector. Then your vector won't have to realocate so much (or even won't do it at all).